# found nil while unwrapping an Optional value swift (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function inside my Cookie.swift

```
func returnMax() -> String {
    var tmpMax: Int = 0
    var typeMax: String = ""
    for (symType, symCnt) in count {
        if symCnt > tmpMax {
            tmpMax = symCnt
            typeMax = symType
        }
    }
    print(typeMax)
    return typeMax
}
```

And I linked a button to my GameViewController.swift as an Action. And when that button is tapped it should display in the log the `typeMax` that is found in my returnMax function.

```
@IBAction func ampAns(sender: AnyObject) {
    cookie.returnMax()
}
```

But instead of getting the desired results, I am getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)`. What could be the possible problem? Thank you!

Comment: In what line was originated your error exactly?

Comment: The error comes from the `cookie.returnMax()`

Comment: Then, please provide the rest of the declarations of the variables used in the function `returnMax`

Comment: `var count = ["amp": 0, "carret": 10, "dollar": 9, "hash": 6, "percent": 3, "tilde": 1]`

Comment: Here is another declaration in my GameViewController.swift: `var cookie: Cookie!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared your variable `cookie` like a optional that always have a value according to your declaration `var cookie: Cookie!` (In this way you're telling to the compiler that this variable there is no need to check for non-value, you assure that when it's accessed it have always a value ), and for some reason you're using the variable before it has initialized. You have to first init the variable and then use it.

Or you can avoid the runtime error using [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html), checking before use the variable like in the following way:

```
@IBAction func ampAns(sender: AnyObject) {
   if let cookie = self.cookie {
      cookie.returnMax()
   }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Oh I see. Let me try this. I'll get back to you on this matter. :D Thanks.

Comment: I put it into my Level.swift already. And it's working. My problem is that I can't add 1 to the dictionary. I am trying to do it like this `count[cookie.getCookie()] += 1` but the error says that "Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int'" What could have gone wrong? Thanks again. :D

Comment: But where is the function `cookie.getCookie()`?

Comment: The function `cookie.getCookie()` is inside my `Cookie.swift`. And it's declaration is

        func getCookie() -> String {
               return String(cookieType)
        }

Comment: Try this instead `count[cookie.getCookie()] =  (count[cookie.getCookie()] as! Int) + 1`

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It worked but I had to tweak it. LOL. Instead of `(count[cookie.getCookie()] as! Int) + 1` it should be `(count[cookie.getCookie()] as Int!) + 1`. I am using xCode 7. I don't know if it's because of that. Thanks again sir. :D

Comment: Sir, I have one question that is still unsolved. I am having a hard time finding out how could I get my background to occupy the whole screen.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that you are not saving your return into a variable.

This change to GameViewController.swift should fix your issue.

```
@IBAction func ampAns(sender: AnyObject) {
  let typeMax: String = cookie.returnMax()
}
```

Comment: cookie is the created custom class in swift. (If I am not mistaken). It has it's own file `Cookie.swift`